# Difference between a VOID function with a string argument VS a function with a string argument that returns a char array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, return

My question is, what is the difference between a function that returns a char array vs a function that is simply void? From my understanding, if you pass a string as an argument, then that string can be altered from within the function without the need to return a new char array

for example,

```
char * my_strcat(char *word, char *appending)
{
    int len = strlen(word);
    for (char *letter = appending; *letter != '\0'; letter++)
        word[len++] = *letter;

    word[len] = '\0';

    return word;
}

void my_strcat(char *word, char *appending)
{
    int len = strlen(word);
    for (char *letter = appending; *letter != '\0'; letter++)
        word[len++] = *letter;

    word[len] = '\0';
}
```

I've tested both and they both work. Why should I use one over the other?

Thanks

Comment: Yes! this is good but when you use Char ** and what the specific string then you have to return char *

Comment: By the way, you aren't reliably terminating the string with a null char.  I'll amend my answer below.

Comment: IMO the `void` version is better style

Answer (score 3):

Returning the original pointer provides the ability to nest function calls more readily:

```
printf("%s\n", my_strcat(name, lastName));
```

As opposed to:

```
my_strcat(name, lastName);
printf("%s\n", name);
```

The version returning `char*` lets you use either of the above styles.

Also, your implementation is not reliably terminating the string with a null char.  You are breaking out of your `for` loop when you encounter a `\0`.  You still want to append that.

Instead of this:

```
for (char *letter = appending; *letter != '\0'; letter++)
    word[len++] = *letter;
```

This:

```
for (char *letter = appending; *letter != '\0'; letter++)
{
    word[len++] = *letter;
}
word[len] = '\0';
```

This would also work (use the side effect of the assignment as the evaluation expression for a loop).

```
while (word[len] = *appending)
{
   appending++;
   len++;
}
```

As I called out in my comment below, I'm not a big fan of using assignment statements as a conditional. I prefer the style you have.

Comment: `while (word[len++] = *(appending++));` :)

Comment: I was tempted to suggest that. But there are so many misunderstood rules about order of evaluation with postfix/prefix operators, that I just prefer to avoid it.  Further, the whole idea of using an assignment statement's evaluation in a conditional looks bugged from the start and only makes code less readable. Many lint like tools would flag `while(x = y)` as a potential bug.

Comment: oops. forgot to null terminate it. edited it now, thanks